# Styling Telerik:RadSpell

Tags: jquery, css, telerik

Anyone have experience with this control?  It's showing in firefox with the close button at the top moved all the way to the right, so I'd like to adjust the css or use jquery on it to fix it.  Does anyone know how this can be done?  I'v been trying using the DialogCssFile attribute, but with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following dll was outdated:

Telerik.Web.UI.dll

I updated it and it rendered fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce the issue, but to no avail. The following code works as expected on my side:

APSX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<telerik:RadSpell ID="RadSpell1" runat="server" AllowAddCustom="true" ButtonText="Check Spelling"
    ButtonType="PushButton" ControlToCheck="TextBox1"  />
```

I would suggest you to post your question also at [Telerik Help Forums - RadSpell](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/spell.aspx), and to provide the code and the CSS that reproduces the problem by your side. A screenshot would be helpful also.